# How to optimize mongodb insert query in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are doing manipulation and insertion of data  in mongo db. So for single insert in mongo db it is taking 28ms. I have to insert 2 times per request. At a time, if I get 6000 requests, I have to insert each data individually and it takes lot more time. How can I optimize this? Kindly help me on this.

```
var obj = new gnModel({
    id: data.EID,
    val: data.MID,
}); 
let response = await insertIntoMongo(gnModel);
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is not vital for the data to be stored immediately, you can implement some form of batching.
For example, you can have a service which queues operations and commits them to the database every X seconds. In the service itself, you can use [mongo's Bulk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) and more specifically for insertion: [Bulk.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/). It lets you queue operations to be executed as a single query(or at least minimal amount of queries/round trips).

It would also be a good idea to serialize and store this operation log/cache somewhere, as server restart will wipe it out if it is stored entirely in memory. A possible solution is **Redis** as it can both persist data to disk and is also distributed thus enabling you to queue operations from different application instances.

You'll achieve even better performance if the operations are unrelated and not dependent on each other. In this case you can use `db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` which will allow mongo to execute the operations in parallel instead of sequentially and a single operation fail won't affect the execution of the rest of the set(contrary to `OrderedBulkOp`).